# How do I get the image of Matplotlib plot through script?

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is my code:

```
hours = [hour1, hour2, hour3, hour4, hour5]
    water_intake = [litres_of_water_consumed1, litres_of_water_consumed2, litres_of_water_consumed3, litres_of_water_consumed4, litres_of_water_consumed5]
    plt.plot(hours, water_intake)
    plt.title('Your water intake')
    plt.xlabel('hours')
    plt.ylabel('litres of water consumed')
```

But instead of using plot.show() and then saving the plot image through matplotlib window
I want to do it through the script
is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [plt.savefig()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) for saving matplot figures.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an image from a `matplotlib` plot as a numpy array image, if needed:

```
ax.axis('off')
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)

# To remove the huge white borders
ax.margins(0)

fig.canvas.draw()
image_from_plot = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
image_from_plot = image_from_plot.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
```